# PySpark: Most efficient way to query from DB for a specific set of ids from an existing data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with these fields: ID1, ID2 and DATE. For each ID1, ID2, and DATE I need to write an SQL statement to extract a new field where I include ID1, ID2 and DATE in the WHERE clause.

What's the most efficient way to code this?

My idea at the moment is to extract ID1, ID2 and DATE fields from the first PySpark dataframe in a list of some sort, and then loop through each 3-pair (ID1, ID2, DATE) and have a SQL statement within the loop. I'm curious if there is a way to only execute 1 SQL statement that does it for all ID1, ID2 and DATE fields from the original PySpark dataframe.

Comment: Can you share a sample data of what you have and what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating an SQL query for each of your dataframe lines, why don't you just do a join query using Spark between your dataframe and the target table (that you can read as a dataframe too) based on the 3 fields you mentionned (ID1, ID2 and DATE).

Using such method will make Spark job optimal since:

- You won't need to collect (send all your data into the Spark driver in form of a list) so all your transformations will be executed by the Spark executors in a parallel manner
- You'll run only one join query instead of as much rows your first dataframe contains

Example here:

```py
joined_df = df1.join(df2, on=["ID1", "ID2", "DATE"], how="inner")
```